# Replicated Master/Slave Servers and databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, database-replication

I have a small Rails app I have deployed on heroku's free tier with only an API and no views to create Books, return a Book's genre, and remove all Books from the database. It looks a little like this:

A `POST request to site.herokuapp.com/add_book?name=harrypotter&genre=fantasy` adds a book.

A `GET request to site.herokuapp.com/find_book?name=harrypotter` returns the genre.

A `POST request to site.herokuapp.com/reset clears the database of all books`

Now that I have this working on a single server I want to replicate it across three servers each with a unique URL, so that I can send my calls to any of the 3 servers and have all their databases containing the same Book entries.

For example if I send a

```
POST request to site1.herokuapp.com/add_book?name=harrypotter&genre=fantasy
```

then send a

`POST request to site2.herokuapp.com/add_book?name=littlewomen&genre=fiction`

I can send a

`GET request to site3.herokuapp.com/find_book?name=littlewomen` .

But if I send a reset call to a server it does not reset the other servers.

I found a two gems called [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) and [Data Fabric](https://github.com/bpot/data_fabric) but it looks like they replicate across databases on the same server, and not on different servers. Also since I am going to be making calls to three different sites will these gems work?

What's the best way to go about this type of database/server replication in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I quite understand your complete use case. Is it that you simply want to distribute reads/writes across the different databases for different API calls ?

If it is a small application why don't you have all 3 applications on site 1, site 2 and site 3 connect to the same database instance ?

Following options:

1. Master Slave Replication

   In your case you would have 1 master db and 2 slave db. Data will be read and written to the master db but will be replicated to the slaves. You can then configure your rails application to do reads across selected databases.

   You can use [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) to distribute writes/reads between slaves and master.

   > When using replication, all writes queries will be sent to master, and read queries to slaves.
2. MySQL Cluster

   I have not used MySQL cluster yet but should be using it soon. If your requirement is to distribute reads/writes across  all the databases while having the data remain consistent across all nodes MySQL cluster looks like a good candidate. The data is distributed across a pool of data nodes. Every MySql server has access to all the data nodes and as result when a server within the cluster changes data example by inserting rows, this new data is immediately accessible and seen by the other MySql servers in the cluster.

   See more here [MySql Cluster](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster-overview.html)